# How to convert sql table data to html table

Tags: javascript, html, json

In javascript, I want to display the sql table data in html format. I attach the screenshot so if any one knows please replay...
[image]

Comment: What's your back-end? If it's nodejs, then if you get data from MySQL, it will return the results as an array of objects in JS, so you'll be able to simply use javaScript .map method to convert results into a HTML table.

Comment: My back-end is python using frappe framework